# get response from nodejs by ajax

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, get, request

I am trying to get a response from a nodejs server using a ajax and i want that the result shows in an html page 
any ideas ??
i'am usig this code :

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var a1,a2;
var r;
var querystring = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

 
 var params = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
 a1=params['a1'];
 a2=params['a2'];
  r=145+678;
   
    res.end('it works');
}).listen(4000);
```

i want to show the value of variable r in an simple html page
thanks for helping and greatest to all stackoverflow members

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/).

Here is an update to your code for very simple rendering of your var r:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
// var fs = require('fs');
var a1,a2;
// var r;
var querystring = require('querystring');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var params = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
    a1 = params['a1'];
    a2 = params['a2'];
    let r = 145+678;
    res.send(`Here is var r: ${r}.`);
}, (e) => {
    es.status(400).send(e);
});

app.listen(4000);
```

If this is too simple, you might want to use `res.sendFile`

Comment: thanks for your answer but what is the code of ajax that let's " r "appears in html page ??

Comment: On ajax `success  : (res) => { console.log("your r =" +res );}`

Comment: This line above: `res.send(\`Here is var r: ${r}.\`);` is sending the response that contains "r" which you can view in the browser. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

i want to show a result of variable "r" in  of an html page 
function showresult() {

$.ajax({

```
url:'127.0.0.1:1234/?state=1',   
success: function(r){
$('#dmm').html(r); 
},
type: 'GET'
});
```

}